# In search of an accounting/sales software

Tags: finance, crm, accounting

my wife just started her own business of petsitting at home, and as she's getting more and more clients and needs to produce official reports, I am starting to look into a piece of software that can handle all this better than a spreadsheet.

I have no idea how such a software is called, but we need to:

- handle a database of clients
- each client has one or more pets, dogs and/or cats, with their pedigree (male/female, neutered or spayed, chip/tatoo number, …)
- we need to keep track of the calendar of the pets we look after at home, to know when there's no more vacancy
- there are different prices depending of the duration of their stay (weekends, working days, consecutive nights, …)
- clients must visit at least once with their pets before their stay, we must keep track of them
- and the main administrative concern: we need to easily produce invoices (for France).

I don't have enough free time to write an ad-hoc software, so does anybody have a recommendation to give?

We're on Macs but I have virtual machines at hand if needed.

Comment: I don't know its frech - capabilities but have used gnu cash in the past for similar situations. It has a not-very-intutive interface and might feel like overkill. Also, by standards of most mac users, it looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

**French/most compatibile desktop software solutions:**

"[Solegis Pro](http://www.logiciel-autoentrepreneur.fr/) is particularly suitable for self-employed entrepreneurs providing specialized services to individuals. This freeware allows you to manage key aspects of your business: sales management (products, customers, sales documents), purchases (suppliers). It includes a financial dashboard displaying the monthly, quarterly and annual turnover." [*-source*](http://ccm.net/faq/32082-free-software-for-entrepreneurs)

"[TerCompta](http://neogia.org/wiki/index.php/TerCompta) offers custom features to meet the needs of self-employed entrepreneurs. This is accounting solution for small businesses, artisans and self-employed entrepreneurs. It meet the needs of simple accounting." [*-same source*](http://ccm.net/faq/32082-free-software-for-entrepreneurs)

[Laurux](http://www.laurux.fr/) appears to handle contact management, scheduling, taxes, bookkeeping, and invoicing.

*Laurux is for Linux. I'm not sure about the first two. The rest of these will run on a Mac:*

[Busy Bee Invoicing](http://bee-software.net/invoice-software/) features client and project management, invoicing, time tracking, multi-currency, and multiple languages. Demo version available. $20.

[iCompta](http://icompta-app.com/) is a personal finance manager for tracking income and expense accounts with professional features (client management, invoicing, scheduling, taxes) that's localized in English, French, and Italian. 30day free trial. $30.

[Vosae](https://www.vosae.com) is based in France, still in beta, and features: timeline, contacts, organizer, and invoicing.

[Banana Accounting](http://www.banana.ch/cms/en/home) is a spreadsheet-based  system: income & expense, double entry, multi currency, multi-language, reports, taxes, etc. Trial version has a 70 transaction limit. ~$137.

**Other desktop solutions:**

There's also Oranged Software's [Studiometry Express](http://oranged.net/studiometryexpress/) for project and client management and invoicing ($100) and [Accounted](http://www.oranged.net/accounted/) for full featured double-entry accounting and reporting ($80). iCal and Address Book integration; multi-currency support. 30day free trials.

If you need more customization & flexibility, there's Kedisoft's [Totals 3](http://www.kedisoft.com/totals/) which is listed at $150 on the App Store and $129 on their website plus a 25% offer ending soon so you can get it for ~$97 now if you do so from Kedisoft directly. Another of theirs you may want to look at is [Invoice](http://www.kedisoft.com/invoice/), which is a less powerful Totals that goes for $40 on their site as well as the App Store. 30day free trials.

Two others that handle bookkeeping and invoicing with multi-currency support are Nano's [Accounts](http://www.nano.com.au/) ($30; also integrates with Address Book) and [Luca](http://cutedgesystems.com/software/Luca/) by CutEdge ($10).

**Cloud-based solutions:**

[Wave Accounting](https://www.waveapps.com/) for invoicing and bookkeeping supports multi-currency (ad supported freeware). For client management [ClinchPad](https://clinchpad.com/), [Insightly](http://www.insightly.com/), and [Really Simple Systems](http://www.reallysimplesystems.com/) all have decent free plans.

[Phreebooks](http://www.phreebooks.com/features/) is an open source ERP application meant for small businesses. All-in-one solution but might be a bit overkill.

Lastly, [Zoho](https://www.zoho.com/) has modules for just about everything. Pricing is per month, free trials are available, and some have limited free plans.